# How can we programmatically add a hyperlink and text to a multi-line text field?

Tags: client-object-model, hyperlink, multiline-text-field

I have a SharePoint list which has a multi-line text field. Can we add a hyperlink and simple text along with it, inside that particular field using the client object model?

If so can someone help me by sharing a piece of sample code so that I can work on my project?

Comment: Yes you can, but can you answer the following first: are you using CSOM (C#) or JSOM (JS)? Is the multi-line text field plain text only or does it allow rich text (bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks)?